# Dropdown is not getting populated

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I am trying to select value from dropdown and corrsponding to that value the listbox should get populated and I m getting values from my json. before adding the ist box my dropdown was working fine but now nothing is being shown in dropdown nor even in the list box...below is my javascript...please I need your help...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.getJSON("data.json",function(obj) {
    var jsObject = $.parseJSON(obj);
        var usedNames = [];
        $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
            if (usedNames.indexOf(value.name) == -1) {
                $("#dropdown1").append("<option value=" + key + ">" + value.name + "</option>");
                usedNames.push(value.name);
            }
    $('<option>', {
        text: 'Select your Option',
        value: '',
        selected: 'selected',
        disabled: 'disabled'
    }).appendTo('#dropdown1');

    $.each(jsObject, function (index, value) {
        $('<option>', {
            text: value['name'],
            value: index
        }).appendTo('#dropdown1');
    });

    $('<option>', {
        text: 'Select your List Option',
        value: '',
        selected: 'selected',
        disabled: 'disabled'
    }).appendTo('#listbox');


    $('#dropdown1').change(function () {
        $('#listbox').empty();

        $('<option>', {
            text: 'Select your List Option',
            value: '',
            selected: 'selected',
            disabled: 'disabled'
        }).appendTo('#listbox');

        var selection = $('#dropdown1 :selected').text();
        $.each(jsObject, function (index, value) {
            if (value['name'] === selection) {
                $('<option>', {
                    text: value['attr001'],
                    value: 'attr001'
                }).appendTo('#listbox');
                $('<option>', {
                    text: value['attr002'],
                    value: 'attr002'
                }).appendTo('#listbox');
                $('<option>', {
                    text: value['attr003'],
                    value: 'attr003'
                }).appendTo('#listbox');
            }
        });
    });
```

My json file

```
[{
  "name": "obs",
  "date": "1458834026000",
  "attr001": "brs1",
  "attr002": "crs1",
  "attr003": "drs1",
}, {
  "name": "hid",
  "date": "1458774000000",
  "attr001": "ffrs1",
  "attr002": "grrs1",
  "attr003": "mno1",
}, {
  "name": "qwe",
  "date": "1425744000000",
  "attr001": "klm1",
  "attr002": "wer1",
  "attr003": "iop1",
}, {
  "name": "rty",
  "date": "1458774000000",
  "attr001": "yrs1",
  "attr002": "qws1",
  "attr003": "prs1"
}]
```

Comment: Please make a JSFiddle with your HTML + code

Comment: have you checked your browser console for any type of errors?. Also try putting in some alert via alert('reached here'); in your code just to get an idea where your code is failing.

Comment: no type of errors in console as well....

Comment: Hi ..please helppppp is naybody around..

Comment: Can you also please post your HTML (containing the select and listbox elements)

Comment: If you had taken the time to create a jsFiddle with your html, js and some basic css code, your question would have been solved hours ago. Just saying.